# Is there a way to remove data from text file after the slash like shown below?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I am trying to remove phone numbers from a text file using sed and awk up until the next comma but have not had any luck.

This...

```
2020-04-13 17:09:58.934,/abc/blahblahblahI/v1/dennisritchie/7408058445,2020-04-13 17:09:58.687,2020-04-13 17:09:58.934
2020-04-13 17:09:59.387,/cde/bunnyrabbit/v1/tea/generate/9161455644,2020-04-13 17:09:59.322,2020-04-13 17:09:59.387
2020-04-13 17:09:59.567,/fgh/scoobybites/v1/shaggy/markup/7672748033,2020-04-13 17:09:59.459,2020-04-13 17:09:59.567
2020-04-13 17:09:59.640,/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/v1/xxx/generate,2020-04-13 17:09:59.624,2020-04-13 17:09:59.640
2020-04-13 17:09:59.796,/yyyy/defoe/v1/aaaaaaaaaal/9820276621?noOfRecords=1&blahlahAccountNo,2020-04-13 17:09:59.523,2020-04-13 17:09:59.796
```

Needs to look like this

```
2020-04-13 17:09:58.934,/abc/blahblahblahI/v1/dennisritchie/,2020-04-13 17:09:58.687,2020-04-13 17:09:58.934
2020-04-13 17:09:59.387,/cde/bunnyrabbit/v1/tea/generate/,2020-04-13 17:09:59.322,2020-04-13 17:09:59.387
2020-04-13 17:09:59.567,/fgh/scoobybites/v1/shaggy/markup/,2020-04-13 17:09:59.459,2020-04-13 17:09:59.567
2020-04-13 17:09:59.640,/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/v1/xxx/generate,2020-04-13 17:09:59.624,2020-04-13 17:09:59.640
2020-04-13 17:09:59.796,/yyyy/defoe/v1/aaaaaaaaaal/,2020-04-13 17:09:59.523,2020-04-13 17:09:59.796
```

Please note I need the data starting from phone number to the next comma gone like in the last line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for the solutions they work on all the lines except the ones looking like below..can you please help

/dcd/manual/v2/profile/9841001122?fields=billingArrangement,billingAccountNo,faId,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825

after running the command it gives be the below output

/dcd/manual/v2/profile,billingAccountNo,faId,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825

But the expected output is like below, can you please help. I am stuck

/dcd/manual/v2/profile,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825

Comment: Welcome to SO and good that you have mentioned you have tried few things. on SO we encourage users to add their efforts(right or wrong doesn't matter since we all are here to learn), kindly edit your post and add samples in there and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this

```
cat data.txt \
  | sed -r 's/(.*)\/[[:digit:]]+,(.*)/\1,\2/g' \
  | sed -r 's/(.*)\/[[:digit:]]+\?[^,]*,(.*)/\1,\2/g'
```

The second replace is because I noticed that the last line in your example is different than the others

Be careful if you have other special cases in you full data set you need to take care of them in a similar way

Comment: Oh my god it worked!! I have been struggling with this for 2 days now. You are a genius. Thank you so much!

Comment: you can simplify the command to `sed -E 's|/[0-9]+[^,]*,|/,|'` or `sed -E 's|/[0-9]{10}[^,]*,|/,|'` (for a more strict condition)

Comment: Thank you for the solutions they work on all the lines except the ones looking like below..can you please help

/dcd/manual/v2/profile/9841001122?fields=billingArrangement,billingAccountNo,faId,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825

after running the command it gives be the below output

/dcd/manual/v2/profile,billingAccountNo,faId,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825

But the expected output is like below, can you please help. I am stuck

/dcd/manual/v2/profile,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825

Comment: well, that one is kinda hard because the comas are screwing with the csv structure, but it is possible. give me a sec. By the way, is that the whole line? does is not have the date as the first part?

Comment: try this ```cat data.txt | sed -r 's/(.*)\/[[:digit:]]+.*,([^,]+),([^,]+)/\1,\2,\3/g'```, but dude, you need to learn regex, coz you will run into these issue more often. This one will take care of all cases btw.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in a single line like as follows.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/[0-9]{10}.*/,"",$2)} 1'  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** As per @kvantour comment to handle corner case try following.

```
awk '
{
  val=""
  num=split($2,array,"/")
  sub(/[0-9]{10}.*,/,",",array[num])
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    val=(val?val"/":"")array[i]
  }
  $2=val
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Comment: This works too, thank you for the quick turn around!

Comment: This is not safe, it might remove numbers in the middle of the directory structure. `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/[/][^/]*$/,"/",$2)} 1'`

Comment: @kvantour, Sure thank you,tried to fix it in EDIT code now.

Comment: Hello Ravinder,

Your solution works for all the lines except for the lines looking like below

/dcd/manual/v2/profile/9841001122?fields=billingArrangement,billingAccountNo,faId,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825

after running the command it gives be the below output

/dcd/manual/v2/profile,billingAccountNo,faId,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825

But the expected output is like below, can you please help. I am stuck

/dcd/manual/v2/profile,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825